# Colors wrong in wine with new x server with 8 bit color

Tags: ubuntu, wine, xterm

I have an old pc game (win95) that I'm trying to play through wine on my ubuntu box. I got it running and all that pretty jazz using this code;

```
$ xinit /usr/bin/xterm -- :1 -ac -depth 8
```

Then in the new window

```
$ ck-launch-session
$ sudo wine "mygame.exe"
```

But for some reason, certain shades of white are black, and visa versa. Is there a way to fix this, or am I stuck with it?

Answer (score 2):

If you had the name of the game, we could look at Wine's AppDB to see the current status of compatibility for the game. But chances are you're stuck with the ugly polygons.

Wine is really hit or miss. The quality of a game/application in wine completely depends on how much time the community has/wants to put into making it work. Seeing as this is an old game, chances are very few people worked on getting it to function perfectly.